# Solve bulb toggling puzzle in non-exponential time?

Tags: algorithm

The bulb on-off problem:

> You are given few switches and few bulbs, not necessarily equal, and each button may connect to multiple bulbs, and when a switch is toggled on, it switches on the already off and off the already on bulbs. We need to find if all bulbs can be lighted up by switching some of these switches?

We can brute-force this problem in O(2^n.n.m.x) (n, the no. of switches;m, total bulbs;x, the maximum no. of bulbs that any switch switches on). Where we try all combinations of switches O(2^n) and check if all bulbs are on O(m) after switching on all bulbs from selected switches O(n.x)

Can this be done in non-exponentiation time, maybe a heuristic.
This somewhat relates to set-packing and set-cover problem and both seem to have approximation algorithms only (NP-hard, IIRC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "yes", you can solve this kind of puzzle in O(min((m^2) n, (n^2) m)) time.

Your problem can be viewed as a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix) of integers mod 2, where multiplication becomes a boolean "and", and addition is boolean "xor".

To make things more concrete:  you can represent the "original" bulb state (with all switches off) as a boolean column vector, the state of each switch as another boolean vector, and the set of bulbs toggled by each switch as the corresponding column of your boolean matrix:

```
output     original         matrix      switches
  [v]        [u]        [m m m m m m]     [x]
  [v]   =    [u]   +    [m m m m m m]  *  [x]
  [v]        [u]        [m m m m m m]     [x]
                                          [x]
                                          [x]
```

This is a set of linear equations under the integers mod 2, and you can solve this kind of problem efficiently using an appropriately modified version of standard [linear equation solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations).

Note that the reason this works is that flipping a switch *always* toggles the same set of bulbs.  If this were not the case, then the equation would *not* be linear, and you could not solve it this way.  In general, if you have "or"'s mixed in with your "and"'s in this kind of problem, you will likely have some variation of the ["SAT" problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), which is NP-complete.

Comment: do you mean (m^2).n or m^(2.n)?

Comment: I'm not sure what he's talking about.  Perhaps he assumes that each bulb is an arbitrary boolean function of the relevant switches, which you would have to explore by trying out all combinations of switches anyway.  My assumption (per my last paragraph) is that flipping a given switch *always* toggles the state of the same set of bulbs, which makes the puzzle solvable in polynomial time...

Comment: yes your assumption is very indeed valid, sorry if i didn't made it clear in the question. Equivalently there exists a fixed function from each switch to set of bulbs.

Comment: Just for those who are interested, solving a system of equations is O(N!) for N variables, which is exponential time, and in this example, you need an independent variable for each possible interaction (switch A could toggle up to x switches), each equation in the resulting matrix will have x times m variables to solve for, so O((x * m)!), not just n or m.

Comment: On the other hand, those who are _not_ interested in wrong answers should ignore Matt Jordan's comment. ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

**Trivial Case, X=1**

For the trivial case of x=1, where each switch can control only one bulb, this is O(N) since you only have to toggle all switches and check whether all lights are on (these are two separate O(N) operations, or rather, O(n) and O(m)).

**Non-Trivial Case, X>1**

For x>1, this cannot be done in linear or polynomial time - it will be at least exponential, but more likely far worse, because the effect of any given switch is not directly related to the effect of any other given switch.  Given a switch A, there is no requirement that switch B does or does not affect any of the same lights as switch A.  It may, but it also may not.  So, no reduction is possible in the relationship between switches.

This is a standard arrangement problem, and can be directly mapped to any of the other major arrangement problems, so the same non-polynomial O() (non-polynomial = exponential or worse) is true for this.

**Cost**

Best case seems to be O(m 2^n), using the equivalent of binary counting but with switches rather than bits, to check every possible combination of switches and test whether all of the lights are on.  Note that how many lights 'x' can be affected doesn't come into play for this solution, because attempting to do so would actually increase the overall O() cost of the computation, and doesn't actually affect the outcome.

Some ways of solving this will actually increase the O(), such as solving a system of linear equations, which is at least O((x*n)^(x*n)), possibly more since it is a probabilistic relationship.  This is because there is no linear relationship between any given switch and any given light, other than in the first trivial x=1 example, so each "variable" in the system of linear equations will have to represent every possible combination of interaction with the lights.

**Some Ideas On Simplifying/Optimizing, With A Cost Though**

One possible simpler way to implement it in software though, and possibly faster for some n,m,x on modern computing hardware due to simpler representation, but with higher estimated maximum cost at O((m+n)!), can be derived from the relationship between the switches and the lights: any given light will be "on" if and only if the number of switches that are "on" which affect that light is odd (the first turns it on, the second turns it off, etc).  This requires finding a permutation across n toggle-maps (where each toggle-map represents the effect of the switch on a light) for each of m lights where every light has 2q+1 switches affecting it, for q>=0.

However, for very large n,m the simple binary counting approach of toggling each switch and testing the solution is likely to be the fastest, since it is just a power of 2.